# setup script and packages are in different locations

Tags: python, setuptools

I'm using setuptools 0.6 to package my code. By default when I type python setup.py sdist, the script must be in the same folder of the package. If my setup script and my package folder are not in the same folder, what can I do to specify the exact path of the package? Thanks

Comment: Your question is a little thin on details; what is your overall directory structure? Your package folder must be contained in the folder with the `setup.py` script, but can be nested deeper.

Comment: In this case, I can not place my `setup.py` script in another disk for example,

Comment: Why would you want to do that? The `setup.py` script is part of your package metadata, you want to keep it close. It *could* perhaps work, but I've never had a need to go to such lengths to stray from the norm.

Comment: You are right, it's just I want to automate some of my tasks. I've found my solution, I'll create another script that call the setup script, thanks!